# Redux-Form FieldArray error always return undefined

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux, redux-form

I have this FieldArray:

```
<FieldArray name="address" component={AddressComponent} />
```

And I use Validatorjs:

```
const validate = values => {
const rules = {
  'address.*.addlineOne': 'required'
}
const validator = new Validator(values, rules, {required: 'This field is 
required'})
validator.passes()
return validator.errors.all()
}
```

But when I access AddressComponent field meta.error its always set to undefined.